# Rotate FontAwesome's location arrow?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

Is there a way to rotate FontAwesome's location arrow (`<i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i>`) when it's used with Bootstrap 3.x?  I'd like to align the pointer with a compass heading.

If not, is there another approach that would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FontAwesome's built in rotate classes:

```css
<i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i> normal<br>
<i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-rotate-90"></i> fa-rotate-90<br>
<i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-rotate-180"></i> fa-rotate-180<br>
<i class="fa fa-location-arrow fa-rotate-270"></i> fa-rotate-270<br>
```

[image: Using .fa classes]

If you need more precise rotation, you can use CSS transforms:

```css
.rotate-arrow-n{
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

[image: Using transforms]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/z0wqu2du/2/)

Comment: Is there a way to make a CSS 'function' that accepts an integer value between 0 and 360 and performs the `rotate()`?

Comment: @craig Unfortunately, CSS doesn't support functions. [LESS sort of does](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature), but it has to be compiled into CSS before being rendered in the browser. If you need that many directions, the best solution is probably going to be to use inline styles to set the direction: `<i class="fa fa-location-arrow" style="-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);transform: rotate(-45deg);"></i>`